# Applescript to Get a Field by Id and Copy to the Clipboard?

Tags: javascript, applescript

I am trying to use Applescript to get a read only field value on a page in Chrome, assign to a variable and then to the clipboard.  I will then retrieve it and paste it to a field.

```
tell application "Google Chrome" to tell active tab of window 1
(execute javascript 
"document.getElementById('b_fieldtograb').Value()")
End Tell
```

I am new to applescripting.  I know you can use the set variable to but when i tried the following:

```
tell application "Google Chrome" to tell active tab of window 1
set my_field to (execute javascript 
"document.getElementById('b_fieldtograb').Value()")
display dialog my_field
End Tell
```

the pop up value just says `msng`.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please provide a valid URL that anyone can reach that has the `'b_fieldtograb'` element ID so we can test the code. If you want help debugging code then your question should conform to [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so we can help without having to go through unnecessary steps to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You ought to be trying to access the `value` property of the text field, but `Value()` is telling it to run a (non-existent) function.

So the two things you need to ensure are that you're referencing the **id** of the text field (and not, say, an **id** of a `div` containing the text field); and that you are referencing a property called `value`, not a function called `Value`.

This snippet works on the [Google.co.uk](http://google.co.uk) webpage:

```
    tell application "Google Chrome" to tell active tab of window 1 to ¬
        execute javascript "document.getElementById('lst-ib').value"

    set my_field to result
    set the clipboard to my_field
```

and returns the text content of the search box, saved it to the variable *my_field*, and sets the clipboard to the value of the variable.